# selenium server time out issue

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

i have installed selenium IDE and selenium server(selenium RC)...while running the test cases in command prompt using phpunit its saying error like

> Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at
>   'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': Timed out after
>   30000ms

i changed in selenium IDE options time out property and while starting the server i gave like

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar [-timeout 7000000]

still same issue saying time out 30000ms

it ll be great if any one can help

thanks in advance ........

Comment: It would be helpful if you check that the server is actually running and not blocked by a firewall or similar first. Just giving a timeout error message is basically calling for further basic debugging the network connection(s) first.

Comment: Selenium IDE settings have nothing to do with Selenium RC settings. BTW: If you just start with Selenium better use WebDriver instead of RC

Answer (score 1):

I just saw the phpunit-selenium code and it seems that they do not support selenium-server above 2.23. You should download earlier version of selenium server (2.23 specifically) and run it. It should work according to their READ-ME file.

Nevertheless I saw that the url they are using to access server i.e.`http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/`was used by Selenium 1 and not webdriver. So I would rather download much oldr version os selnium from http://release.seleniumhq.org/ and try it.

One more thing. the right way to define the timeout is `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -timeout 7000000` that is, no square brackets.

Hope this helps.. :)